# How to Create a Clipboard Synchronisation Program

Tags: node.js

I like to Create a Clipboard Synchronisation Program.

That work across Windows, Mac and Linux.

Technologies: Electron and Ionic.

Primary Priority : Security

How to Sync Clipboard across devices without storing or touching user data?

How to Identify and Authenticate a user and enable communication between his devices? Without storing Clipboard data or IPadress to the Server?

Need help with system design

Comment: [Stack Overflow isn't a place that will architect an entire application for you, especially not one of this magnitude](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252139/can-i-ask-design-related-questions-on-stack-overflow) - these types of questions are much too broad for the Q&A format here. Please review [ask], as well as what's considered on topic per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can sync clipboard data across devices without storing or touching user data is to use end-to-end encryption. This means that the clipboard data is encrypted on the sender's device and can only be decrypted on the recipient's device using a unique key that is not stored on the server.
2. To authenticate users, you could use a combination of public-key cryptography and authentication tokens. The user could generate a unique public/private key pair on each of their devices, and the server could use these keys to establish secure communication channels between the devices.
3. you could have the devices communicate directly with each other using peer-to-peer networking, this would help avoiding storing any user data on server.

There can be more approaches for all of these but these are few you can try